# Get group of checkboxes value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a group of checkboxes like generated in php

```
<?php
     foreach($estados as $estado){
          $html = '<div class="checkbox chk_estado">';
          $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" class="estate_check" value="" chk_id="'.$estado->id_estat.'" />'.$estado->estat.'</label>';
          $html .="</div>";

          echo $html;
      }
 ?>
```

I'm trying to get the check_id attribute of the checked member of the class but I get  a 0 value with somecheckboxes checked

```
var checked  = $('.estate_check').attr('chk_id');
```

Comment: check_id??? You are using chk_id

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a typo mistake.

Comment: Are you aware that `.attr()` gets the value of an attribute for the *first* element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Try something like this https://codepen.io/Svenx/pen/dmbaoW

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store something in the HTML element, use `data-*` attribute. In this case, use `data-check-id="..."`.

```
<div class="checkbox chk_estado">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="estate_check" value="A" data-check-id="1">
    Something
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox chk_estado">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="estate_check" value="B" data-check-id="2">
    Something
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox chk_estado">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="estate_check" value="C" data-check-id="3">
    Something
  </label>
</div>
```

Then, this is how to get all checked checkbox.

```
const getAllChecked = () =>
  Array.from(
    document.getElementsByClassName('estate_check')
  )
    .filter(x => x.checked)
    .map(x => x.dataset.checkId);
```

You will get an array like this.

```
Array [ "1", "2" ]
```